# What are the @keyframes identifier rules in CSS3?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I am working on an animation and I was wondering what were the rules for the @keyframe identifier.

For instance, I was doing the following but it didn't work.

Code:

```
  #banner {
  width: 468px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  animation-name: #banner;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}
@keyframes #banner {
  from: {background-color: red;}
  to: {background-color: green;}
}


<div id="banner">Just a banner</div>
```

Comment: One of the first links on google for "css @keyframes" query: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes PS: you're almost there, just check the documentation slightly more carefully in how you name keyframes element, and how you specify `from` and to`

Comment: @zerkms  Relevant also this other page linked from the one that you provided https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/custom-ident

Answer (score 0):

The `@keyframes` rule specifies the animation code.

The animation is created by gradually changing from one set of CSS styles to another.

During the animation, you can change the set of CSS styles many times.

Specify when the style change will happen in percent, or with the keywords "from" and "to", which is the same as 0% and 100%. 0% is the beginning of the animation, 100% is when the animation is complete.

Tip: For best browser support, you should always define both the 0% and the 100% selectors.

Note: The !important rule is ignored in a keyframe

Read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes